# Save output window position in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I prefer to have output window in vertical to the right side. Every time I open a new project it resets.

How do I save the window configuration settings in netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

You can **dock** the Output window in Netbeans. In order to do that reset the current window settings by select **Window** -> **Reset Windows**.

Once again goto **Window** and select **Output**.

After that it will looks like this on the bottom of the screen

[image: screenshot 1]

Now drag and drop this Output window to Right part of your NetBeans window (vertical center).

There you can dock the window like this.

[image: screenshot 2]

Now it's ready to work with new configuration.